# Draw the change portion of image on another image

Tags: c#, image, merge

suppose i have two images img1.jpg and img2.jpg. using some routine i could extract the difference between two images. now difference is saved in another bitmap variable called diff

here is code

```
Bitmap diff = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(diff);
g.DrawImage(secondImg, 0, 0, bounds, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
g.Dispose();
```

i know the difference in terms of rectangle and also save the difference in diff variable. now i want to merge or draw this difference on my first image. i tried with code like

```
Graphics g1 = Graphics.FromImage(firstImg);
g1.DrawImage(secondImg, 0, 0, bounds, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
g1.Dispose();
```

but it is not working because when i open my first image img1.jpg then i am seeing any changes in that image. i want to draw the changes on my first image img1.jpg. what is wrong in my code which is not being able to dump or draw the changes on first image.

basically i have to reconstruct img1, if i have img2 and difference between img2 and img1.
please guide me. thanks

Comment: Are you saving the image back to img1.jpg after you're done drawing?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: i use DrawImage which will automatically update img1. am i right?

Comment: It will update the `Bitmap` object, but it will not save the changes to the filesystem... There should be a `firstImg.Save()` if you want to update the file

Comment: can u plzz give me small code snippet what u have said. thanks